# Python Pandas concatenate/merge DataFrames using index or column identifiers

Tags: python, pandas, merge, dataframe, concatenation

I would like to use the 'pandas.concat' method to merge two DataFrames, but I don't fully understand all 'pandas.concat' arguments. I've got two DataFrames, which have the same identifying variables in the columns, but differ in one single column.

```
import pandas as pd
dict_data = {'Treatment': ['C', 'C', 'C'], 'Biorep': ['A', 'A', 'A'], 'Techrep': [1, 1, 1], 'AAseq': ['ELVISLIVES', 'ELVISLIVES', 'ELVISLIVES'], 'mz':[500.0, 500.5, 501.0]}
df_a = pd.DataFrame(dict_data)
dict_data = {'Treatment': ['C', 'C', 'C'], 'Biorep': ['A', 'A', 'A'], 'Techrep': [1, 1, 1], 'AAseq': ['ELVISLIVES', 'ELVISLIVES', 'ELVISLIVES'], 'inte':[1100.0, 1050.0, 1010.0]}
df_b = pd.DataFrame(dict_data)
```

df_a

```
        AAseq   Biorep  Techrep Treatment   mz
0    ELVISLIVES  A   1   C   500.0
1    ELVISLIVES  A   1   C   500.5
2    ELVISLIVES  A   1   C   501.0
```

df_b

```
    AAseq   Biorep  Techrep Treatment   int
0    ELVISLIVES  A   1   C   1100
1    ELVISLIVES  A   1   C   1050
2    ELVISLIVES  A   1   C   1010
```

I can add the column the following way:

```
df_m = df_a.copy()
df_m['inte'] = df_b['inte']

     AAseq  Biorep  Techrep Treatment   inte
0    ELVISLIVES  A   1   C   1100
1    ELVISLIVES  A   1   C   1050
2    ELVISLIVES  A   1   C   1010
```

My real data looks much more complex and I'm afraid that the method above could lead to the wrong order of values in the rows (specially since I want to use 'pandas.melt' beforehand).

When using:

```
dfm = pd.concat([df_a, df_b])

     AAseq  Biorep  Techrep Treatment   inte    mz
0    ELVISLIVES  A   1   C   NaN     500.0
1    ELVISLIVES  A   1   C   NaN     500.5
2    ELVISLIVES  A   1   C   NaN     501.0
0    ELVISLIVES  A   1   C   1100    NaN
1    ELVISLIVES  A   1   C   1050    NaN
2    ELVISLIVES  A   1   C   1010    NaN
```

The concatenated DataFrame extends the values rowwise leading to NaN vals.

**Question**: How can I achieve the same result (shown above) using 'concat'?

Thank you for your support!

Comment: Have you actually tested whether that method will break your dataset?

Comment: No I have not. The dataset is large (rows 3847440, cols 16), and I don't know how to test for the break. How can I test for a break?? I'm asking for the concat method since I'm hoping that there is an argument(s) that will rely on the indices of the two dataframes to concat/merge them.

Comment: Create smaller dataset for tests.

Comment: fair enough :)   I would just like to have certainty that the concatenation doesn't break the dataframe. If you know how to achieve the same result using the concat method please be so kind and enlighten me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

```
 print pd.concat((df_a, df_b['inte']), axis=1)
```

you can get

```
        AAseq Biorep  Techrep Treatment     mz  inte
0  ELVISLIVES      A        1         C  500.0  1100
1  ELVISLIVES      A        1         C  500.5  1050
2  ELVISLIVES      A        1         C  501.0  1010
```

Is this what you expected ?

---

Or maybe you have more complicated data like this - see different values in column `Treatment`

```
        AAseq Biorep  Techrep Treatment     mz
0  ELVISLIVES      A        1         A  500.0
1  ELVISLIVES      A        1         B  500.5
2  ELVISLIVES      A        1         C  501.0

        AAseq Biorep  Techrep Treatment  inte
0  ELVISLIVES      A        1         C  1100
1  ELVISLIVES      A        1         B  1050
2  ELVISLIVES      A        1         A  1010
```

and you need to keep order using values from columns `AAseq Biorep  Techrep Treatment` then use `merge`

```
import pandas as pd
dict_data = {
    'AAseq': ['ELVISLIVES', 'ELVISLIVES', 'ELVISLIVES'],
    'Biorep': ['A', 'A', 'A'],
    'Techrep': [1, 1, 1],
    'Treatment': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    'mz':[500.0, 500.5, 501.0]
}
df_a = pd.DataFrame(dict_data)

dict_data = {
    'AAseq': ['ELVISLIVES', 'ELVISLIVES', 'ELVISLIVES'],
    'Biorep': ['A', 'A', 'A'],
    'Techrep': [1, 1, 1],
    'Treatment': ['C', 'B', 'A'],
    'inte':[1100.0, 1050.0, 1010.0]
}
df_b = pd.DataFrame(dict_data)

print pd.merge(left=df_a, right=df_b, on=['AAseq', 'Biorep', 'Techrep', 'Treatment'])
```

result:

```
        AAseq Biorep  Techrep Treatment     mz  inte
0  ELVISLIVES      A        1         A  500.0  1010
1  ELVISLIVES      A        1         B  500.5  1050
2  ELVISLIVES      A        1         C  501.0  1100
```

Comment: Yes that is what I've expected, however I'm getting an Error when trying your code: """TypeError: Cannot concatenate list of ['DataFrame', 'Series']""" I've tried your exact code as well as """pd.concat([df_a, df_b['inte']], axis=1)""". I can only execute the statement if I remove the column index: """pd.concat((df_a, df_b), axis=1)""" but that results in duplicate identifyer columns.

Comment: I tried on your example data and it works - I use pandas 0.14.0 (`print pd.__version__`). Check your version.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH!! The 'merge' function is EXACTLY what I was looking for/missing. Awesome. Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Eventually you could try to update pandas to newer version (`pip install -upgrade pandas`) if you stiil need `concat()` ;)